# undefined method 'images' instagram API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I'm using the Instagram API to get images with certain tags, but Rails said undefined method 'images' when I'm showing the images in the view.

Here's the error Rails gives:

```
 undefined method `images' for #<Array:0x007f9ee7460608>
```

Here's the controller:

```
  @photos = Instagram.tag_recent_media("cats")
```

Here's the view source:

```
   <% @photos.each do |photo| %>

       <%= image_tag photo.images.standard_resolution.url %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: You should include the full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `images` is an attribute of the `data` attribute of `@photos`. Try this instead:

```
<% @photos.data.each do |datum| %>
  <%= image_tag datum.images.standard_resolution.url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks! Makes sense now that I think about it.